# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in redirect with middleware in Django

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I wrote this program so that the user would be moved to my target page if it had certain conditions.

**This is my custom Django `middleware`**:

```
def check_userprofile_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Profile conditions goes here. 
            if profile_condition:
                return redirect(reverse('base:edit_user_profile'))
        return response
    return middleware
```

If I use `return` in `if` statement, it redirects to 'base:edit_user_profile' url, But after that I see this error on browser:

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

If I don't use `return` in `if` statement, everything goes correct,except redirection!

What is wrong with this?

Comment: could it be, that the profile condition is also true for the redirected page, so the redirected page tries to redirect to the redirected page, which would try to ...

If that's the case, then you just had to check the url and if the url is the redirected page you should not redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I do that? @gelonida

Comment: I got that! Thank you.I add this and problem has been solve: ` while not (request.path == reverse('base:edit_edupanel_user_profile')):
                    return redirect(reverse('base:edit_edupanel_user_profile'))`  Please write your this answer and I will accept your this. @gelonida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tips of @gelonida I recieve to answer. I did add this line and problem was solve:

```
        while not (request.path == reverse('base:edit_edupanel_user_profile')):
            return redirect(reverse('base:edit_edupanel_user_profile'))
```